# Add Guest Reader site user for a File

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, rest

I want to know how I can add a Guest Reader site user on my OneDrive. Since a Guest Reader is for a particular file, I want to know if I can add such a user through REST API.
I am looking for something like

```
https://{mysite URL}/_api/Web/siteusers
```

*Method* POST

*Body*

```
{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.User' }, 'LoginName':'SHAREPOINT\\reader_blabla'}
```

where blabla is the UniqueId of my file (with dashes removed)

*Content-Type*

```
application/json;odata=verbose
```

*Accept*

```
application/json;odata=verbose
```

Response

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "-2130575276, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException",
    "message": {
        "lang": "en-US",
        "value": "The user does not exist or is not unique."
    }
}
}
```

I have read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn531432.aspx) that you can add site users to sitegroups, so lets say if I do as the instructions say,
I have a limited access group with id 14

```
https://{mysite URL}/_api/Web/sitegroups(14)/users
```

The body and headers are the same. Still I get the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your user exist in O365?

Comment: No, I believe guest users (Guest Reader/Writer users) are site users and not O365 users (since their userId is null)